# How to manually add a package to Swift without Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode9

I'm trying to manually add JTAppleCalendar to my Swift project, but when I go to import JTAppleCalendar, or try to create a new Cocoa touch class of class JTAppleCell, it doesn't show up. I copied in the sources folder into my project as shown below.[image]

Is there a step I'm missing so that the project will read the JTAppleCalendar files?

Comment: If you manually add the files to your project, then there is no "importing" of anything because you will not have a Library to import. Just use it normally without an import function.
You will however have a lot of errors. To make them go away, just go to the files you have imported and add `"Import UIKit"` to the top of them.

Comment: So if I'm trying to create a new JTAppleCell file, I just need to add Import UIKit at the top? It doesn't seem to be automatically reading the class type though when I do

Answer (score 0):

The color of the `Sources` folder should be **yellow** not blue. Make sure to choose `Create groups` when dragging the source to your project. And then it will work.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, so I'm trying to drag the sources folder in, and even when I select Create folder references, it still doesn't turn yellow. If the folder is already created, is there another way to change it to make it yellow instead?

Comment: I suggest that you delete the sources folder from finder and XCode, then add it with references again.

Comment: I tried deleting the sources folder from finder and Xcode, then dragging it back in and creating the folder references but the folder is still blue

Comment: It seems like blue folders are the create references, and create groups are the yellow ones?

Comment: If create groups can make that folder yellow, that's it. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I tried it and 'create groups' is right. I updated the answer.